# How to test for end of line when reading a double in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eof

Ok so I have this problem. For some reason whenever I read a file in Linux. It has an extra carriage return at the end  of the line. This is causing errors in my program. So I would like to know how would I test for the end of line condition whilst extracting doubles from each line

```
 fin >> variable
```

The file is formated like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: More information about the format would allow for better advice.

Comment: How are you currently reading the file? Show your code.

Comment: It probably has an extra '\r' because it came from Windows.

Comment: Nope, the contents of the file is created by another part of the program, so im guessing thats where it must have come from

Comment: The extraction operator (`operator>>`) eats whitespace, including carriage return. If you do `fin >> variable`, you shouldn't be able to detect any carriage returns, much less extra ones. Please describe in more detail what your program is doing, and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the extra carriage return, this loop should work:

```
double d;
while( fin >> d ) {
  std::cout << "The value is: " << d << "\n";
}
```